# one to many relationship query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I have two tables. These are client and project. Each client has many projects and each project related with one client. I want to output all the projects in the view template which is related with each client. Please help me

## Project Model

```
public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Admin\Client');
    }
```

## Client model

```
 public function projects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Admin\Project');
    }
```

I want to output like below in the blade template:

```
id -| Client_name |- client_company |- contact_number-|- project_list
----|-------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------
  1 |  x          |  x@.com         |xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  |  first project
    |             |                 |                 |  second project
    |             |                 |                 |  Third project
  ----------------|-----------------|-----------------|--------------------  
  2 |  y          |  y@.com         |xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  |  first project
                                    |                 |  second project
                                                      |  Third project
```

Answer (score 3):

> First, you need to get all client with eager load projects like the
>   below example:

**$clients = Clients::with('projects')->get();**

> Now in the view template, you need to use following code:

```
<?php

foreach($clients as $client) {
       // Here you can get client details in $client object
       //$client->name give you client name

   foreach($client->projects as $project){
          // Here you can get projects details in $project object
         // $project->name give you project name
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks . Your solution has helped me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by this way

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'foreign_key', 'other_key');
```

For more 
[Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I have already gave the relationship between two tables. Thank you for your effort

Comment: I am telling you that you can also give the additional key to get result. If you want your data from another column of db

Comment: yeah, It is a good way to access other data from another column of db. Now I have understood about this. Thanks to you for your code.

Comment: If it's working you can mark this answer as an accepted answer so future users will get help.